# Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation

Tags: java, hibernate

getting this kind of error while try to run this in eclipse

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:94)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:115)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
at creatingNewTableAndInserting.Testshoping.main(Testshoping.java:30)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernateconfiguration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <propertyname="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql</property>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

shoping.java

```
package creatingNewTableAndInserting;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class shoping {
         private int itemId;
         private String itemName;
         private long price;

@Id
public int getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(int itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

public long getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(long price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

Testshoping.java

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;


public class Testshoping {

    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(shoping.class).configure();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    new SchemaExport(configuration).create(true,true);
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);   
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
shoping s = new shoping();
        s.setItemId(1);
        s.setItemName("phone");
        s.setPrice(12000);
session.save(s);
session.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

}

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.training.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenServlet</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MavenServlet</name>
<description>MavenServlet</description>
<properties>
    <hibernate.core.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.core.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>hiber</warName>
                <warSourceDirectory>
                    ${basedir}/WebContent
                </warSourceDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```